# Upgrading Xcode issue

Tags: ios, xcode, upgrade

I am currently working with Xcode 4.5.2 and I'd like to upgrade it to version 4.6. Will installing the new version completely replace the previous one? If so, is it possible to just "extend" your current version and keep the SDKs you already have? I wouldn't like to lose the compatibility with my current projects...

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> "Will installing the new version completely replace the previous
>   one? If so, is it possible to just "extend" your current version and
>   keep the SDKs you already have?"

It is possible to install them side by side which allows you to start picking up newer versions as early as preview while being able to fallback to the stable version you've been working with.  I roll between versions in parallel. Remember that developer tools have bugs too :)

Go to Applications and rename Xcode to Xcode45.  Login to your developer account at apple, look under it for download older versions (which actually has newest version) and download the Xcode dmg for 4.6.  Run it and drag to Applications.

Comment: I do as soon as it is released in case there's some new bug/issue that blocks my specific apps.

Comment: After I use it awhile, I delete the older one.

Comment: I just wait until the x.y.1 release :)

Comment: No reason to.  The strategy above allows you to start using it in preview.

Comment: @maddy - There are, indeed, some quite valid reasons to have multiple versions.

Comment: @HotLicks I agree there are times where multiple versions is appropriate (such as the latest stable and a beta). But why would anyone need 4.5 and 4.6 (both non-beta)?

Comment: @rmaddy, non beta developer tools are not immune to bugs :)  I can't count the number of times with various software that I've upgraded only to go back (or wish I could).

Comment: @maddy - Sometimes (though perhaps not in that case) there are significant differences in features.  (And newer versions are not always an improvement, feature-wise.)

Answer (score 3):

Xcode 4.6.x supports iOS 4.3 through 6.1. Xcode 4.5.x supports iOS 4.3 through 6.0. Upgrading to 4.6 is not going to result in you losing any compatibility.

Comment: Are all those SDKs included in the package, or should I import them somehow?

Comment: There's only one SDK per Xcode. And that is all you need. Xcode 4.6 includes the 6.1 SDK. But you can still have a deployment target back to iOS 4.3.

Comment: Ok, in that case, can Xcode "alert" you if you are making use of any feature that is not present in or is not compatible with previous iOS versions?

Comment: Sadly no. The best thing you can do is properly test your app against each main release of iOS. Either with real devices or by installing the different versions of the simulator. If your deployment target is 4.3 then test against 4.3, 5.0, 5.1, 6.0, and 6.1. You can also make use of the "API difference" docs from Apple. BTW - all of this has been needed since iOS 3.0 came out. This is nothing new.

Answer (score 0):

If you download from the developer web site rather than the app store you can have multiple versions of Xcode installed at the same time. At one point I had 4 or 5 versions.